# What is the meaning of the "()" in the return type of function calcDecrement?

Tags: swift, function

I just started learning Swift and came across function types and how to return them. I just want to know what the `()` means in the return value of function `calcDecrement`? I know the function returns a reference to the inner function `decrementer` so is the `()` return type for a function?

```
func calcDecrement(forDecrement total: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var overallDecrement = 0
    func decrementer() -> Int {
        overallDecrement -= total
        return overallDecrement
    }
    return decrementer
}

let decrem = calcDecrement(forDecrement: 30)
print(decrem())
```

Comment: It's not just `()`, it's the whole `() -> Int` thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`() -> Int` is the return type and this represents a function that takes no arguments and returns an `Int` as the result.

`decrementer` matches this exactly, so it is good as a function to return.

If the return type took an `Int` as a parameter, then the return type would be `(Int) -> Int`.

See Apple’s documentation at [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID174) for more details about the type of a function.